# “_OBJC_CLASS_$_”, referenced from: error in xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode

So today I ran into a major problem. I got a problem involving my viewcontroller on xcode 4.3.2 as seen in this error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SecondViewController",
referenced from: objc-class-ref in Birdflix_ProViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ThirdViewController", 
referenced from: objc-class-ref in Birdflix_ProViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FourthViewController",
referenced from: objc-class-ref in Birdflix_ProViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Author",
referenced from: objc-class-ref in Birdflix_ProViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I noticed that these errors only appear when I program IBActions linking my viewcontroller to additional classes. If I delete the IBActions the errors disappear. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 95):

Finally found the answer. In your target settings, locate build phases and navigate to compile sources. Once there just ad the .m file that is getting the error to the list.

Comment: other thing is to make sure your 'Target' is selected rather than 'Build and Test' while copying/adding any resource

Comment: @Mobihunterz, your comment helped me out. Thanks. +1

Comment: Remember to run Clean before building. That solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you!! Still a life saver in XCode 6 (beta)! Even solved a case for me with pods (libPods.a).

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue too. Just a note for anyone else running into this error, make sure the `.h` is added to the Headers section and the `.m` file added to Compile Sources section.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following method worked.

In target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources I had all .m files including those that were giving issue.

Simply I removed those .m files which were giving issue.